# Retrieving remote network printers using CIMinstance/WMIObject in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Here's what I have going on. For some reason when I run these commands locally they work fine, but if I run them on remote machines nothing happens. I've tried using "get-wmiobject" too. Same thing. Any thoughts on why this could be? Thanks!

```
$cimopt = New-CimSessionOption -Protocol DCOM
$cimsession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $computerhostname -SessionOption $cimopt

#### printers
get-ciminstance -cimsession $cimsession -ClassName Win32_Printer
get-ciminstance -cimsession $cimsession -ClassName win32_printer | %{if ($_.default) {$_}}

#### mapped drives
get-ciminstance -cimsession $cimsession -ClassName Win32_MappedLogicalDisk
```

Comment: Do you have mapped drives and printers on these other computers? I would think it will grab your settings of your session.

Comment: The machines have both mapped drives & network printers for the logged-on user; it's that information I'd like to get if at all possible.